# A_ThisHotkey and A_PriorHotkey only take into account keys declared as hotkeys

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to write a script that upon release of `Ctrl`, it will tell me if it was the most recently pressed key or if another key was pressed since `Ctrl` was down.

So if `F` was pressed while `Ctrl` was down, I need to know.  The "while holding down" key should be any key not just a modifier like `Ctrl`.

I wrote the following, but I am having a peculiar issue with it. It seems it will only inform me of  a key being pressed, **IF** the key itself is declared as a hotkey in the script.

So with the following script, if `F` was pressed, I will be informed but as soon as I comment out the line `^f::  ; Do Nothing`, I will not be informed if `F` is pressed:

```
#singleinstance, force
#Persistent
#NoEnv
#Warn, All, OutputDebug

~LCtrl::
ToolTip, % "Most Recent Key: " A_ThisHotkey "`n Prior Key: " A_PriorHotkey   
Return
^f::  ; Do Nothing
```

With this in mind, I would have to declare every keyboard and mouse key on my system to get my program to work. This is not ideal and it will simply not work in my main script.

Is there a way to populate `A_ThisHotkey` and `A_PriorHotkey` with keyboard/Mouse Keys that are **not** declared as Hotkeys in the script?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: See  [A_PriorKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Variables.htm#PriorKey).

Comment: Aah! That did it, the "Hot" distinction was lost on me. You should have proposed this as an answer. You still can.

Comment: And [this way](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=300318&sid=1cfb05736b1fa9ca41fc2dea75479eb1#p300318) you can get the key prior to A_PriorKey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Hotkeys.htm) in AHK perform tasks and have to be defined by the user.
Therefore [A_ThisHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Variables.htm#ThisHotkey) and [A_PriorHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Variables.htm#PriorHotkey) allways refer to hotkeys already defined in the script.

To get the name of the last pressed keyboard/mouse key use [**A_PriorKey**](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Variables.htm#PriorKey):

```
#NoEnv
#singleinstance, force
#Warn, All, OutputDebug
#InstallKeybdHook
#InstallMouseHook

~LCtrl:: ToolTip, % "Most Recent Key: " A_ThisHotkey "`n Prior Key: " A_PriorKey
```

Comment: Brilliant. Now I understand even better. Thank you.